# Play sound over SIP without sound card

Tags: audio, sip, voip

Is it possible to play custom audio (*.wav file) over VOIP (SIP) without sound card being installed on SIP client machine? All my needs is to perform SIP call and play custom sound message.

Comment: You need some kind of sound card whether it is on the motherboard or as a separate card.  Most computers today have them on the motherboard. Are you asking if you need some type of additional card?

Comment: No it is virtual machine server with no physical sound card.

Comment: What kind of virtual machine? Some of them can emulate sound cards.

Comment: @KevinJunghans I don't understand. Why would you need a sound card unless you plan to emit actual sound from the computer. My understanding is that the OP wants to accept a phone call and play a sound into the phone call (such as a recording that the remote party will hear). You don't need a sound card for that.

Comment: @Celada I may not understand the question correctly. I assumed the SIP client was on the receiving side of the call and the user wanted to listen to the audio that was sent over. But if the question is can you send a wav file over SIP without a sound card on the sending machine then the answer is yes. But you have to translate the wav file to an appropriate codec before transmitting.

Comment: I agree with @KevinJunghans . I guess we each understood the question differently. Pavel, I'm afraid this means you need to clarify which one you mean :-)

Comment: Yes I mean I want to play a sound into the phone call. Transmit *.wav file into the call => other side will hear this message. Thanks for answer. And could you give some links to study how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transmit a recorded audio in the form of a WAV file over a SIP signal if you convert it to the appropriate codec first.  This does not require a sound card to transmit this audio.  A sound card is only required to listen to the audio. Which codec to use depends on the platform.  Here is a [link for converting to appropriate codecs when using Asterisk](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Convert+WAV+audio+files+for+use+in+Asterisk). There are a lot more if you just Google something like "audio codec conversion".

A simpler approach is to just use a platform that does this for you, like [Voxeo Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/products/voicexml-ivr-platform.jsp). This is a software only IVR solution that has a 2 port version for free.  It is easy to install and program using the open standard [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/).  It will play back audio files recorded in a WAV file format and the telephony interface is SIP.